# Find #ID to add/remove class

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#table").click(function () {
    $(".slidebar").addClass("expand");
  });
});
```

It's mean when I click on `<div id="table">` , class `slidebar` will add `expand`.

Now my HTML code has double class `slidebar` like this

```
<div id="point" class="slidebar">....</div>
<div id="mark" class="slidebar">....</div>
```

I basically want to when I click on `<div id="table">`, just only `<div id="point" class="slidebar">` add class `expand`.

How can I do this with Jquery?

Comment: `$("#point").addClass("expand")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the ID selector, and not Class selector to do that, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#table").click(function () {
    $("#point").addClass("expand");
  });
});
```

But just in case you wish to use the class, you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#table").click(function () {
    $("#point.slidebar").addClass("expand");
  });
});
```